# get text from word using DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I am trying to get text from `.docx` file and when use this code in visual studio it's working well but when uploading to server I get the error:

> Error: Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true)) {
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Body body
        = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
    totaltext = body.InnerText;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must register the dll "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll" on each machine you want to use your code.

Register the dll on the server and it should works just fine

Comment: Thanks Its works now , But if file have image 'File contains corrupted data', there is anyway to ignore image and get only text  ?

Comment: you'll have to delete images tag from your body with something like body.Descendants<Drawing>().ToList().Foreach(i => i.Remove());